# Specify the git URL location of Jenkinsfile in a `GitHub Organization` job

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-organizations

When I create a new Github Organization job and then configure it.  In the 'Project Recognizers' section I only have the ability to select 'Project Jenkinsfile' (with no input fields), which will use the Jenkinsfile in the root of each repository.  I would like to be able to have a way of recognising the project but then using a different Jenkinsfile from a different GitHub repository.

I do not want the project developers to be able to modify the workflow of the project.  How can I specify to use a Jenkins file from a URL location in this type of Job?

Comment: It sounds like using a Jenkinsfile is simply not the way to go for your needs.  Part of having a configuration that exists on the outside, especially within the project, is that you need to be able to trust the people with access.  You may want to build a freestyle job and do everything the old fashioned way within the jenkins UI.  That way you can restrict access to the build process down to a user by user case. 

EDIT - You can still use pipelines in a freestyle project, you'll just define the scripts in the jenkins UI rather than a file in the repository.